# How can i define the same sound for all buttons in my app? What is the best practise?

Tags: android, button, audio

I’ve tried to create a class and make objects. Next I call method to play a sound
But is it recommended ? It seems like I have to cope and past the same two lines to every button. What if I want to add feature that will turn off all sounds ?

```
public class ButtonClickSound extends AppCompatButton implements View.OnClickListener {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public ButtonClickSound(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ButtonClickSound(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ButtonClickSound(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOnClickListener(this);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.click_sound_basic);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        playButtonClickSound();
        // Tutaj dodaj kod obsługi kliknięcia przycisku
    }

    public void playButtonClickSound() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }


}
```